# React Native WebView crashes when trying to download

Tags: android, react-native, webview, expo

I have an application build with Expo Project. I try to implement a feature using WebView. All the web can load properly from the WebView. But, inside the WebView page, we have a download feature. Whenever I try to click the download button the application crash immediately. I don't know why because I can't see any error message in the terminal and Expo didn't show up any error message as well. The app just crashed. Is there any way to handle errors like this from React Native WebView guys? So at least the app won't be crashed.
P.S: it only happens in Android only.

Comment: Can your share code to reproduce the error?

Comment: If anyone is still facing this issue today, the first thing I would suggest is to update the web view package.